# Limit of simple functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm studying measure theory this semester and my professor put this question on the exam. I didn't know even how to start it, can someone give me a hint?

Let $(X,\mathcal{B}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f: X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ a positive measurable function. Consider $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of positive real numbers such that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \infty$. So there exists $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathcal{B}$ such that

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\chi_{A_n} \;\;\; \forall x \in X
\end{equation}

Comment: You must have $f : X \to \mathbb R_+$ since $a_n$ are positive and $\chi_{A_n}$ are positive.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with a positive function $f_0 : X \to \mathbb [0, \infty]$. Then let 
$$A_1 = \{ x \in X \mid f(x) \geq a_1 \},$$
$$A_2 = \{ x \in X \mid f(x) - a_1 \chi_{A_1}(x) \geq a_2 \},$$
$$A_3 = \{ x \in X \mid f(x) - a_1 \chi_{A_1}(x) - a_2 \chi_{A_2}(x) \geq a_3 \}$$ and so on.

The sequence $s_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \chi_{A_k}$ converge pointwise to $f$ by monotone convergence.

Comment: I know. But Affonso wanted a hint and I gave him one knowing that it was a bit vague about the convergence.

Comment: I just realized it was a hint. That's why I deleted my comment. In any case, the proof is more than just invoking monotone convergence of $s_n.$ It uses the fact that the $\sum a_n$ diverges.

Comment: Together with $a_n \to 0$. Just divergence of $\sum a_n$ isn't enough, since then we could have $a_n = 1$ for all $n$, and then the sum would never get close to any non-integer value.

Comment: Yes, you also need $a_n\to 0.$ My point is that just because $s_n$ increases and is bounded doesn't immediately imply that $s_n\to f.$

Comment: Actually, I think that I've never really seen the fact that if $0 < a_n \to 0$ with $\sum a_n = \infty$, and $M>0$, then there's a subsequence converging to $M$. But it shouldn't be too difficult to prove.

Comment: You are not dealing with  subsequences. You have a sequence $0<(a_n)\to 0$ with $\sum a_n=\infty $ and a sequence $(s_n)$ defined as you have done and you need to prove that $s_n\to f$. It is clear that $s_n$ converges, but it is not immediate that it converges to $f$. I did it by contradiction. It's not hard but it's not trivial either. Or maybe I am not understanding your comment.

Comment: Pointwise we have subsequences: $a_n$ belongs to the subsequence at $x$ if $x \in A_n$. My last comment was based on such sequences, but considered in a more generic manner as sequences of positive numbers.

Comment: Yes I see. But then for each $x$ you have a specific subsequence of $(a_n)$ call it also $(a_n)$ for convenience, and the problem is the same: to show $\sum a_n\to f(x).$