# Integrability with respect to sum of measures

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $\Sigma$ a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ and $\mu_i,i\in\mathbb{N}$ measures with domain $\Sigma$ and $\mu=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mu_i$. Then $\mu$ is a measure with domain $\Sigma$. Let $f$ be a non-negative real-valued function defined for $\mu$-almost all $x\in X$. I would like to prove that $f$ is $\mu$-integrable iff it is $\mu_i$-integrable for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\int f d\mu_i<\infty$.

The definition for integrability is as follows (for non-negative functions defined almost everywhere): $g$ is $\nu$-integrable if there is a non-decreasing sequence $(g_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of non-negative $\nu$-simple functions with $\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\int g_i d\nu<\infty$ and $\lim_{i\to\infty}g_i(x)=g(x)$ for $\nu$-almost all $x\in X$.

Simple functions are finite $\mathbb{R}$-linear combinations of indicator (or characteristic) functions of sets in $\Sigma$ with finite measure, i.e. functions of the form $s=\sum_{i=0}^m a_i\chi_{A_i}$ where $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$, $A_i\in\Sigma$ are sets with finite measure and $\chi_{A_i}$ are indicator functions of those. The integral of a simple function $s=\sum_{i=0}^m a_i\chi_{A_i}$ is $\int s\nu=\sum_{i=0}^m a_i\nu(A_i)$ and in our particular case $\int s d\mu=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\int s d\mu_i$ holds.

The problem I have is in the direction $\Leftarrow$ of the proof of the equivalence. Assume $f$ is $\mu_i$-integrable for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\int f d\mu_i<\infty$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ pick a non-decreasing sequence $(f_{n,i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of non-negative $\mu_n$-simple functions with $\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\int f_{n,i}d\mu_n<\infty$ and $\lim_{i\to\infty}f_{n,i}(x)=f(x)$ for $\mu_n$-almost all $x\in X$. Now I would like to use these simple functions to define a non-decreasing sequence $(f_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of non-negative $\mu$-simple functions with $\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\int f_i d\mu<\infty$ and $\lim_{i\to\infty}f_i(x)=f(x)$ for $\mu$-almost all $x\in X$. I tried $f_i=\min_{j\leq i}f_{j,i}$. Then I think that we get the bound for the integrals but not the convergence $\mu$-almost everywhere. On the other hand $f_i=\max_{j\leq i}f_{j,i}$ gives the convergence but not the bound for integrals anymore. What's the correct path here?

Comment: We can assume $f\geq0$ by working only with $f^+$ and $f^-$. Let $C=\sum_i\int fd\mu_i$. For any simple function $0\leq s\leq f$, you have that $\int sd\mu=\sum_i\int sd\mu_i\leq C$ (first equality is $\sigma$-aditivity of measures, definition of integrals for simple functions, and associativity and commutativity of series of non-negative terms), because $\sum_{i=0}^n\int sd\mu_i\leq\sum_{i=0}^n\int fd\mu_i\leq C$ for all $n$. Therefore $\int fd\mu\leq C$.

Comment: @logarithm I have to demonstrate the condition in the definition of integrability. What sequence of simple functions are you suggesting?

Comment: My argument is for any simple function in $0\leq s\leq f$ (for a non-negative $f$). If the integral of all of them are bounded by a constant, then the supremum of their integrals is necessarily finite.

Comment: @logarithm I understand this but how does it help in showing that $f$ is $\mu$-integrable in this case?

Comment: $\int fd\mu$ is the supremum of all $\int sd\mu$ for all simple functions $s$ with $0\leq s\leq f$. If all $\int sd\mu $ are bounded by a finite $C$, then the supremum is finite.

Comment: By the way, the $\Leftarrow$ only works for non-negative functions. If we take $f([0,1])=\{1\}$ and $f([-1,0))=\{-1\}$ and $\mu_n([0,1])=\mu_n([-1,0))=n$, then $\int fd\mu_n=0$, $\sum_n\int fd\mu_n=0<\infty$. But $\int fd\mu$ doesn't exists because $\int|f|d\mu=\infty$.

Comment: But first I have to show that $f$ is $\mu$-integrable so that $\int f d\mu$ makes sense. For that I have to construct a sequence of simple functions with uniformly bounded integrals and converging to $f$ almost everywhere. And you are right about $\Leftarrow$ working only for non-negative functions. I think that for the general case we need $\sum_i\int|f|d\mu_i<\infty$ instead of $\sum_i\int f d\mu_i<\infty$.

Comment: You are confused about what is needed in this problem. Maybe it is because you are not clear that to have a sequence of simple functions converging to $f$ you only need its measurability. That is given, because all the $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ are defined on the same $\sigma$-algebra. What this problem is about is to prove that all of them are bounded by a finite constant, which then shows that the supremum of all of them (what is called $\int fd\mu$ by definition) is finite.

Comment: @logarithm You may be right. I will have to think through what you have said. Thank you.

Comment: Haven't checked the answers, but you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316148/limit-of-simple-functions) and probably many other posts in this site have it. Any text you are using should have it too, before any work for defining Lebesgue integral is done.